# How do I create a Select option that links to another page in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a select list with several options. I wanna choose one then it straight away direct me to a page. I don't wanna have any submit button. How do I do that in Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with javascript. If you are using jQuery you can do something like this.

```
$(function(){
  $("select#your_select_field_id").change(function(){ 
    if ($(this).val() == "the desired field") {
      window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    }  
  }
});
```

I didn't tested the code, it could contain syntax errors, but you can get the idea form this snippet.

Comment: Since no other option except Javascript, I found this: `<select id="mySelect" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != ''){window.top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value}">
<option value="http://www.test.com">link</option>
<option value="http://www.Pineapple.com">Pineapple</option>
</select>`